# perl Excel::Writer::XLSX write_formula encoding

Tags: excel, perl

I am trying to use Excel::Writer::XLSX. Most things already successfully, but I struggle to get a formula into a cell.

```
use utf8;
```

is set

I am trying to set the formula into the cell with the following statement:

```
$av_obj_excel_worksheet_DATA->write_formula( 'a3', '=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(gw_col_gwuPMBo,(MONTH(gw_col_DATUM)=1)*(gw_col_gwuPMBo<>0),"_empty")' );
```

I have the extracted the .xlsx-file (since it is a simple zip-file) and had a look at the relevant xml of the spreadsheet.

The result is:

```
_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(gw_col_gwuPMBo,(MONTH(gw_col_DATUM)=1)*(gw_col_gwuPMBo&amp;lt;&amp;gt;0),"_empty")
```

but the result should be, since I created an .xlsx-file manually and had again a look at the relevant xml-file of the relevant spreadsheet:

```
_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(gw_col_gwuPMBo,(MONTH(gw_col_DATUM)=2)*(gw_col_gwuPMBo&lt;&gt;0),"_empty")
```

I seems to me some unicode problem.

Unicode is difficult to understand and - I regret - I don't realy do!

Can someone help me what to do to get the correct form of the formula into the .xlsx file (or related .xml-file of the relevant spreadsheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I already experimented with encode and decode and now found the solution:

```
$av_tmp_STRING = '=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(gw_col_gwuPMBo,(MONTH(gw_col_DATUM)=1)*(gw_col_gwuPMBo<>0),"_empty")';
$av_tmp_STRING = decode( 'UTF-8', $av_tmp_STRING );
$av_obj_excel_worksheet_DATA->write_formula( 'a3', $av_tmp_STRING );
```

the hurdle was that I did not see the result durging debugging the script. But the correct string was written to the .xlsx-file.

Sometimes, by thinking, searching and trying it comes to a positive result.